# Click on a link does not trigger jquery fadeIn

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fadein

In my rails app, I'm using jquery fadeIn to fade in my navbar and some text in the home page, as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.jq-fadein').hide().delay(600).fadeIn(2000);
});
```

It works fine everytime I reload/refresh the page, but when I click on the Home page button in navbar the effect does not work!

I suspected that maybe it's not sending a get request but as I found out it does:

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2016-03-01 01:44:18 +0100
Processing by SiteController#index as HTML
  Blog Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "blogs".* FROM "blogs"  ORDER BY "blogs"."id" ASC LIMIT 3
  Rendered site/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.3ms)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 125ms (Views: 98.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)
```

How can I get it to fadein when I click on the home page button in navigation bar and not refreshing the page?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It appears you are missing the home button click logic. Could you add that as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only calling the fadeIn function on $(document).ready(), which fires when the pages initially loads.  That's why you see the fade every time you refresh.

Adding a fade when you click the home button should be something simple like this:

```
$('#homeButton').click(function() {
    $('.jq-fadein').hide().delay(600).fadeIn(2000);
});
```

Comment: I'm still very new to jquery, but now it's making sense. Thanks a lot :)